# How to make a 2D contour plot with given data point in Octave/MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, plot, octave

I have a matrix whose three columns correspond to x, y and f values. I want to make a contour plot of `f(x,y)` in the x,y plane from these data with Octave/MATLAB.

Let's say, the matrix `M` is

```
x1 y1 f1
x2 y2 f2
x3 y3 f3
.  .  .
.  .  .
```

I found the function [contourf](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/contourf.html) requires `f` to be a matrix (whereas I have a vector with corresponding points).

How to generate this plot?

Comment: In general in this kind of situation your best bet is to probably interpolate your actual values over a standard ndgrid, and _then_ pass it to the relevant surface-plotting functions.

Answer (score 1):

The `x`, `y`, and `z` variables that you pass to `contourf` are all matrices of the same size.  For every point you need an `x`, `y`, and `z` value.  You can use `meshgrid` to make matrices that have all the combinations of x and y values.

This example is from the doc for `contourf`.  I added some comments to explain what is happening

```
% Create a vector of x values
x = linspace(-2*pi,2*pi);
% Create a vector of y values 
y = linspace(0,4*pi);
% Make matrices with all combinations of x and y values for plotting
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
Z = sin(X)+cos(Y);
contourf(X,Y,Z)
```

This is the result of the above code
[image]

Comment: I know how to make a meshgrid for x,y, but I only have value of `z` (or `f`) corresponding to a specific `(x,y)` in the data. I cannot write something like `Z = sin(X)+cos(Y);`, my `z` is not a matrix. I only have a list of (x,y,z)

Comment: Assuming you have all the combinations of x and y, perhaps you can use the reshape function to make the x, y, and z values into matricies.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use contour().
contourf() is for functions, contour for data.

Comment: Please add more details. How do I use contour starting from the matrix `M`, as shown in the question?

Comment: No, `contourf()` is for [filled contours](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contourf.html).